# Would like all numbers to be in scientific notation

Tags: formatting

I'm trying to get output with all of my numbers in scientific notation.  Mathematica doesn't seem to use scientific notation until the exponent is 6.  These are all machine numbers.  I thought I could use `NumberForm` and put a formula in for `ExponentFunction` using `Log[10,x]` to force the exponent.

So I did this:

```
NumberForm[123456., ExponentFunction -> (Floor[Log[10, 123456.]] &)]
```

[image: correct answer]

However, when I try this and reference the number, as follows, it doesn't work.

```
NumberForm[123456., ExponentFunction -> (Floor[Log[#]] &)]
```

[image: incorrect answer]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For debugging, you could do `NumberForm[123456., 
 ExponentFunction -> ((Print[{##}]; Floor[Log[#]]) &)]` to see what arguments are fed to the pure function.

Comment: @CarlWoll Thank you for that.  Clearly I didn't understand how the pure function worked.  I'm still a little confused, but at least I can now use it in this context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`ScientificForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScientificForm.html)

```
list = 123.456*10^Range[-6, 6];

ScientificForm[list]
```

[image]

There is also [`EngineeringForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EngineeringForm.html)

```
EngineeringForm[list]
```

[image]

Comment: Or, if one really wants to use `NumberForm`: `NumberForm[list, ExponentFunction -> (1 Quotient[#, 1] &)]` and `NumberForm[list, ExponentFunction -> (3 Quotient[#, 3] &)]`, respectively.